# Split variable having comma seprated value into two random part in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, split

I have string="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8" I want to split string in 2 different variable with unique values as below
string_p1="1,2,3,4,5" string_p2="6,7,8"

Here i dont want any specific defined logic while splitting variable any random splitting is okay.
but i need to ensure that i am not  missing any number present in variable string

Please suggest bash script to get the above results ?

Comment: Your expected result is far from an equal split of the original list.

Comment: length of string == `15`; using `bash` integer-based math `$((15/2))` == `7`; first 7 characters are `1,2,3,4` leaving the 2nd half as `,5,6,7,8`; if this isn't what you want then you'll need to update the question to provide more details on how you come up with `1,2,3,4,5` and `6,7,8`; also, why is the question tagged with `arrays`?

Comment: You've made it *too* general now. `string_p1=$string` and `string_p2=` would satisfy your relaxation of the original constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea using an array and some basic `bash` string manipulation:

```
string='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'
IFS=, arr=( ${string} )                 # break on comma delimiter, store in array
```

Result:

```
$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="1" [1]="2" [2]="3" [3]="4" [4]="5" [5]="6" [6]="7" [7]="8")

$ len="${#arr[@]}"
8
```

To generate a random number between `0` and `8` (length of `arr[]`), eg:

```
$ n=$(( RANDOM % len ))
$ echo $n
2                                       # obviously this will vary between 0 and 8 based on value of $RANDOM
```

Build our final strings:

```
$ string_p1=${arr[@]:0:n}
$ string_p2=${arr[@]:n}
$ typeset -p string_p1 string_p2
declare -- string_p1="1 2"
declare -- string_p2="3 4 5 6 7 8"
```

Now replace spaces with commas:

```
$ string_p1="${string_p1// /,}"
$ string_p2="${string_p2// /,}"
$ typeset -p string_p1 string_p2
declare -- string_p1="1,2"
declare -- string_p2="3,4,5,6,7,8"
```

**NOTE:** because the split is based solely on `$RANDOM` there is a good chance one of the resulting strings can be empty (eg, `n=0`); OP can add more logic to  address this issue as needed (eg, if `n=0` then set `n=1` to ensure `string_p1` is not empty)

---

Taking for a spin with a different input:

```
string='3,24,666.83,2,9,0,34,23,45,12,1'
IFS=, arr=( ${string} )
len="${#arr[@]}"
n=$(( RANDOM % len ))
string_p1=${arr[@]:0:n}
string_p2=${arr[@]:n}
string_p1="${string_p1// /,}"
string_p2="${string_p2// /,}"
typeset -p len n string_p1 string_p2
```

This generates:

```
declare -- len="11"
declare -- n="8"
declare -- string_p1="3,24,666.83,2,9,0,34,23"
declare -- string_p2="45,12,1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with this:

```
string="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"

echo ${string:0:${#string}/2}
echo ${string:${#string}/2}
```

and it splits the string in half, this is the output:

```
1,2,3,4
,5,6,7,8
```